# My CSS does not seem to be working?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with my CSS.

- It's not working even though it is linked correctly to my HTML
  document.
- The files *are* in the same folder.
- Both files are saved in the correct format.
- From what I can see, I don't see anything wrong or missing from the
  CSS.

[The CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l227W.jpg)

[The HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sesvf.jpg)

Comment: add a forward slash before style.css = /style.css?

Comment: @Keith — No. "The files are in the same folder"

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: yeah its going to be hard to tell without seeing the folder locations of each

Comment: @Keith — "The files are in the same folder"

Comment: Inside HTML you use header class and in css u declare tags

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your css matches your html, you don't have any of those tags in your html so the css wont do anything.

Your html references class="header" (btw you are missing quotes around your class in your html, you should add those in.) your css just has header

You should have .header { ... } not just header {..}

Comment: I've added the (.) before each class in the CSS file, but it still does not seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Have you fixed your html so its class="header" not class=header as well? I'd also suggest just adding in something like  body {background:red;} just to check the file can be found. You should also close your body tag (it looks like it is missing the closing </body> it goes just before </html>

Comment: Yes, I have. There is a change when it's run on Chrome. It seems to be responding correctly to the "text-align=right" line as the h1 "Peter Ewing Driving School" is correctly placed.

Comment: That means your css is working now.Your background on your header is #ffffff which is white so you wont see that. If you change it to red or blue see if that works (it will make it more obvious for you)

Answer (score 0):

You're using header class.
It should be in double quote.
i.e

In css file you've not added dot(.) before class header.
Class should be added with dot(.) and id with hash(#)

Try this :)

In HTML5, header is a tag.
You can use it 
Ref. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp